# Calculating consistent estimators

Tags: self-study, variance, unbiased-estimator, consistency

Let $X_1, X_2,\dots$ be $iid$ random variables with density $f(x|p), 0<p<1$ being the unknown parameter. Suppose that there exists an unbiased estimator T of $p$ based on sample size 1, i.e. $E(T(X_1))=p$. Assume that $var(T(X_1))<\infty$.

I need to find an estimator $V$ for $P$ based on $X_1\dots X_n$ such that $V$ is consistent for $p$.

I assumed $T(X_1)$ would be the place to start from and calculated an unbiased estimator of $p$ based on $T(X_1)$ that is $V=(T(X_1)+\dots +T(X_n))/n$ only to realize that the consistent estimator need not be unbiased. I am left stray when I try to calculate Variance to prove consistency by Chebychev.

Part B of this question is given that Sn is the minimum variance unbiased estimator of $p$ based $pn$ the sample of size $n$. Prove $var(S_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Taking help from the part B, I can deduce that $S_n$ can be a consistent estimator of $p$.
In fact, any estimator whose variance $\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ can be taken as a consistent estimator.
Also, the estimator can be used to estimate any parameter, because it does not participate in the RHS of the chebychev inequality.

I find my conclusions particularly illogical. Please point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: if T(X1) is unbiased, how can you transform T(X1)+.....+T(Xn) to make it unbiased? Hint: compute the expectation of T(X1)+.....+T(Xn).

Comment: okay, I corrected the typo. I took the unbiased estimator as V=(T(X1)+.....+T(Xn))/n. So this does become an unbiased estimator, also the variance also goes to zero as n goes to infinity. But my reasoning that I developed, are they all correct?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Used the math typesetting. Thankyou for pointing it out. Can you help me with the reasoning?